# Trouble Sending data via a POST request

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, postman

I have to send some data at an endpoint (flask endpoint). The data I need to send is an image and a variable. I am using the below code to send the data but I am getting an error `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'read'`

**Sender Code**

```
data = {'image': open(fl, 'rb'), 'var': 0}
res = requests.post(url, files=data)
```

**Reciever End Point**

```
file = request.files['image']
f1 = file.read()
f2 = np.fromstring(f1, np.uint8)
f3 = cv.imdecode(f2, cv.IMREAD_COLOR)

var = int(request.form.get('var'))
```

I tried the following changes but that results in other error `TypeError: Object of type BufferedReader is not JSON serializable`

***Changes #1***

```
data = {'image': open(fl, 'rb'), 'var': 0}
res = requests.post(url, json=data)
```

***Changes #2***

```
data = {'image': open(fl, 'rb'), 'var': 0}
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json'}
res = requests.post(url, json=data, headers=headers)
```

***Changes #3***

```
data = {'image': open(fl, 'rb'), 'var': 0}
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json'}
res = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)
```

I can easily send and receive image but I am unable to send variable data

I can send data (image and variable) easily with [Postman App](https://www.postman.com/)

[image]

Comment: Have you tried getting the code directly from postman? It is a feature where you press the code button below send and you can get a requests code of python

Comment: @Yash Thanks for the suggestion, getting code from postman was helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed issue by using below code

**Sender Code**

```
payload = {'var': '1'}
files = {'image': open(fl, 'rb')}
res = requests.post(url, data=payload, files=files)
```